# Install Neo4J in air gapped environment

Tags: neo4j

Neo4J desktop requires registration, there is no internet access so that is not possible.  It fails with 'unrecoverable authentication error'.  Are there any work arounds.  For instance an older version of Neo that did not require registration?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is alternate downloads. 
Download the zip for your platform

Desktop's audience is developers not deployment. 
One of its goals is to provide a gui for managing several servers and databases.

Desktop will install java if needed, then the chosen server.
As you speak of restricted environment, you'll have to deal with the prerequisites and unzip the server yourself.